ubuntu apache default page appears on some devices
I have completed a server move of an application (ILIAS which is a learning management system).  I have changed the A Record. The application is displayed normally on most end devices. On some, however, the standard default Ubuntu apache page is displayed. These are completely different devices. This are  Can DNS caches or browser caches play a role here?
Standard function to clear Browser Caches but not working.


If DNS was to blame, and those clients somehow still resolved the host name to the old IP address, then the default page you are seeing would have to come from your old server.

Or maybe these clients make their requests via IPv6, and your AAAA record is still pointing elsewhere.

Or these clients do not send a proper Host header, and therefor your Apache does not know which Vhost to route the request into.

Hello @CBroe, thanks for your repley. There is no AAAA record in DNS settings. How can the clients be made to use the correct header?

In apache conf was no server ilias(www). This was the cause of the problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
